# Mobile App Developer Guide - Shipify App asking for HTTP POST

Tags: mobile, app, heroku

I have been working through the Mobile App Developer guide in prep for my App Developer certification and ran into 2 issues when developing the mock apps Shipify and Delivery Tracker.

1. After I step through all the steps for the Shipify app deployment I get this popup

   "First make HTTP POST to "/" w/ Salesforce signed-request. HTTP GET to  "/" is not allowed"
2. When i attempt to preview my app DeliveryTrakr I get the following error

   HTTP ERROR 500

   Problem accessing /canvas.jsp. Reason:

   ```
   PWC6033: Unable to compile class for JSP
   ```

   PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
   The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

   Caused by:

   org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Unable to compile class for JSP

   PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
   The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

   ```
   at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:123)
   at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:296)
   at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:376)
   at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:437)
   at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:608)
   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:360)
   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:486)
   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:380)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:565)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:479)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:521)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:227)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1031)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:406)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:186)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:965)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:349)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:449)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:925)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:857)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:230)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:76)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:609)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:45)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:599)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:534)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
   ```

I have followed the guide step by step, have connected heroku, git, ssh keygen correctly and made sure to double check as well but my apps keeps failing. Any help and guidance regarding these points would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to figure out what the issue was. The tutorial never specified that I needed to create and deploy my Salesforce Developer Domain.

After I created the domain and deployed it the shipify app was able to connect.