# Shipify example in Mobile App Developer Guide doesn't work

Tags: canvas, heroku, documentation

When I try to run the Shipify example in the Salesforce1 Mobile App Developer Guide, I get this message.

`First make HTTP POST to "/" w/ Salesforce signed-request. HTTP GET to  "/" is not allowed`

Does anybody know what's going on?

---

I found the code that generates the message.

`https://github.com/forcedotcom/Shipify-Node-App/blob/master/views/index.ejs`

`$(document).ready(function(){
          if(access_token == '' || instance_url == '' || warehouseId == '') {
            alert('First make HTTP POST to "/" w/ Salesforce signed-request. HTTP GET to  "/" is not allowed');
            return;
          }`

But I don't have enough context to know why the access_token would be an empty string.

---

The alert box that pops up when I click Shipify from the Chatter tab says this:

`An embedded page at blooming-crag-22270.herokuapp.com says:
First make HTTP POST to "/" w/ Salesforce signed-request. HTTP GET to  "/" is not allowed`

A    $ heroku logs --tail    yields this when I click Shipify from the Chatter tab:

`` 2016-07-14T13:19:59.149392+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2016-07-14T13:19:59.149986+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2016-07-14T13:20:01.098059+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2016-07-14T13:20:02.906473+00:00 app[web.1]: Running on: port 51419
2016-07-14T13:20:02.913713+00:00 app[web.1]: process.env.RUNNING_ON_HEROKU = true
2016-07-14T13:20:03.429120+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2016-07-14T13:20:04.242851+00:00 app[web.1]: POST /signedrequest 200 34ms - 5.69kb
2016-07-14T13:20:04.354310+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /stylesheets/Mobile-Design-Templates-master/common/css/app.min.css 304 10ms
2016-07-14T13:20:04.355901+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /stylesheets/Mobile-Design-Templates-master/common/js/main.min.js 304 7ms
2016-07-14T13:20:04.356897+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /stylesheets/Mobile-Design-Templates-master/common/js/jquery.touchwipe.min.js 304 7ms
2016-07-14T13:20:04.358890+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/Mobile-Design-Templates-master/common/js/jquery.touchwipe.min.js" host=blooming-crag-22270.herokuapp.com request_id=74806678-6863-439d-96d4-b035167bd407 fwd="168.93.73.226" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=18ms status=304 bytes=237
2016-07-14T13:20:04.234185+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/signedrequest" host=blooming-crag-22270.herokuapp.com request_id=c4e82bcc-8ba9-4411-bedb-59c32acbdc81 fwd="168.93.73.226" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=33ms status=200 bytes=6004
2016-07-14T13:20:04.357081+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/Mobile-Design-Templates-master/common/css/app.min.css" host=blooming-crag-22270.herokuapp.com request_id=4e9905f9-0127-4a20-9eca-534e5375ed15 fwd="168.93.73.226" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=18ms status=304 bytes=239 ``

---

Aha!  Output in the console log is this, with the code below.

`access_token = "00D36000001Fb8u!AQQAQNKzBEm5lv6ZPmT8IWxDwnts9zUcCcXJyS.BgGqTYgEJkdhXoXDyDEI109ZTDJfQlfIO_q88HHOq1q6w8e2iB_6.Ib43", instance_url = "https://na30.salesforce.com", warehouseId = ""`

```

```
    //Note: Values of the variables below are set by the server.
    var access_token = '<%= oauthToken %>';
    var instance_url = '<%= instanceUrl %>';
    var warehouseId = '<%= warehouseId %>';

    console.log('access_token = "' + access_token + '", instance_url = "' + instance_url +
            '", warehouseId = "' + warehouseId + '"');

    $(document).ready(function(){
      if(access_token == '' || instance_url == '' || warehouseId == '') {
        alert('First make HTTP POST to "/" w/ Salesforce signed-request. HTTP GET to  "/" is not allowed');
        return;
      }
        getInvoices();
    });
```

```

It's warehouseId that is missing.  I bet the code is just fragile, and it doesn't handle missing data well.  How do I set up the data so that a warehouseId will be there?

---

Elsewhere in the code, it says that warehouseId is optional.  I removed the check for warehouseId, and it worked!

`$(document).ready(function(){
                    // Some places in the code, it suggests that warehouseId is optional.
                    // I'll try just taking it out, since I don't have one.
          // if(access_token == '' || instance_url == '' || warehouseId == '') {
                    if(access_token == '' || instance_url == '') {`

Comment: did u find the solution for this(First make HTTP POST to "/" w/ Salesforce signed-request. HTTP GET to "/" is not allowed) problem ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the warehouseId is optional, and we don't have one.  I changed the code so that it doesn't quit if warehouseId is missing.

In the views/index.ejs file:

`$(document).ready(function(){
        // Some places in the code, it suggests that warehouseId is optional.
        // I'll try just taking it out, since I don't have one.
        // if(access_token == '' || instance_url == '' || warehouseId == '') {
            if(access_token == '' || instance_url == '') {`

Comment: I still wonder how other people made the code sample work.  Did they have a warehouseId?

Answer (score 2):

Please double check that you are using the `POST` method (not GET) in the Canvas Settings as shown here.

[image]

Specifically, step 10 mentioned in the guide is important here.

> 10. In the Access Method drop-down list, select Signed Request (POST).

This is by default set to `GET` and is most likely causing the issue at your end.

Comment: Hi, Gaurav.  The Canvas App Settings - Access Method is set to Signed Request (POST).  (I tried to paste an image but I failed.)  I edited the question and included the code that is generating the error, if that helps.

Comment: Another fellow said that the problem went away when he "created and deployed his Salesforce Developer Domain" ( http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/106341/mobile-app-developer-guide-shipify-app-asking-for-http-post ) but I don't know what that means.

Comment: Is there some org where this is working, that I can compare to?

Comment: I added the heroku logs to the question.  Looks to me like /signedrequest gets posted first, contrary to what the error message seems to be saying.

Comment: I figured out which data item is missing.  Probably the program just doesn't handle it well when the data isn't set up.